# How can I enforce a unique together constraint for an AppEngine datastore model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My problematic situation:

```
class pxm(db.model):
    meeting = db.ReferenceProperty(Meeting)
    person = db.ReferenceProperty(Person)
```

I do not want to have repeat combinations of `meeting` and `person`. There needs to be a unique constraint that includes both columns.

How do I add such a constraint to my model?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not in English.

Comment: Perhaps your problem is the , instead of the period in your code. Also, is this a class definition?

Comment: Please update the question title to be in English as well.

Comment: I agree with @rayryeng - unless the question title is changed to English as well, this question should remain closed.